# SQL code not running properly for joining tables with subquery

Tags: sql

Here is my code...I tested the subquery by itself and it works. I joined the two tables alone and that works. When i combine them I get an error that command not properly ended.

```
select employees.last_name,departments.department_name,departments.location_id, locations.city
FROM hr.employees, hr.departments, hr.locations
where employees.department_id = departments.department_id
AND departments.location_id = locations.location_id
WHERE commission_pct =
(select commission_pct 
from hr.employees
where commission_pct IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: commission_pct is a single value, but the subquery returns a set of results.  Does it help to have: `select top 1 commission_pct`.  Also, can you copy/paste the error?

Comment: and change `WHERE commission_pct` to `AND commission_pct`

Comment: Oh, and you have two where clauses.

Comment: How can i convert the commission_pct to a set of results that the sub query is displaying

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong.  I don't know what RDBMS you're using, but at the very least you can't have two `WHERE` clauses - you should be using an `AND` instead of the second `WHERE`.  You also should probably be using an `IN` instead of an `=` for the subquery, as the subquery can return more than one result and `=` will fail when it does.

You're also using a deprecated join syntax - you should be using ANSI join syntax.  E.g.

```
select employees.last_name,departments.department_name,departments.location_id, locations.city
FROM hr.employees
INNER JOIN hr.departments
ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
INNER JOIN hr.locations
ON departments.location_id = locations.location_id
WHERE commission_pct IN
(select commission_pct 
from hr.employees
where commission_pct IS NOT NULL)
```

You may also want to consider doing a `JOIN` of some sort against the subquery instead of a `WHERE`, although that may not matter as much.